# Rubymine Live Template (or plugin) to scaffold YARD (documentation) comments for methods

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine, live-templates

[Rubymine integrates with and supports portions of YARD](https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2019/06/yard-support-in-rubymine/) (a Ruby documentation tool). Using `option + enter` (Mac) on a Ruby method definition shows two options:

- `Add @param tag`
- `Add @return tag`

Such that:

```rb
class song
  def initialize(artist, name, duration)
  end
end
```

Expands to:

```rb
# @param [String] artist
# @param [String] name
# @param [Integer] duration
class song
  def initialize(artist, name, duration)
  end
end
```

My goal is to mimic this behavior using a ["Live Template"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/using-live-templates.html) or a ["Plugin"](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html) (whichever is more appropriate).

I noticed that Ruby "Live Template" functions don't include the `methodParameters()` function that other languages have; however, it looks like you can access the `_editor` object in a Live Template groovy script (which may offer a workaround).

I am unfamiliar with IntelliJ plugins, but there appears to be an old plugin that offers similar functionality.

**Questions:** I want to be able to quickly scaffold/expand YARD documentation for classes, methods, and blocks that use "context clues" to fill in portions of the template. Which approach is most appropriate? How can I use that approach to solve my problem?

Comment: You've also created a request on the RubyMine tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-27372) so probably it's better to follow the discussion there

Comment: Thanks, @Olivia! I wasn't sure if these were different enough audiences, or if discoverability/support was common for JetBrains tracker issues. I thought if either became stale, I could put a bounty on this question to attract attention.